# jHipster - Loading data

Tags: h2, jhipster

Is there a workflow for adding data with jHipster?

I want to add static data for the H2 database in the first instance, is this process different when using MySql, postgresql?

I note there is a users.csv which is loaded via liquibase, I'm guessing I create another csv and load that.

Cheers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same for all SQL databases as it uses Liquibase, you must create a Liquibase changelog that uses `loadData` to load your CSV file from `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/data` and refer to it from `master.xml`.

Additionally, you can also tag your changelog so that this data is only loaded for H2 by setting a conditional `dbms="h2"` or use a condition on Liquibase context `context="dev"` that you can then set in `application*.yml`.